# Perturbed eigenvectors in the divide-and-conquer eigenvalue algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, recursive-algorithms

I'm reading Trefethen & Bau's *Numerical Linear Algebra* (SIAM, 1997). In chapter 30, they discuss the divide-and-conquer eigenvalue algorithm for computing "eigenvectors as well as eigenvalues" for a symmetrical tridiagonal matrix $T$, as they state explicitly on page 229. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_eigenvalue_algorithm) has an equivalent summary.

The idea is this: split $T$ into two new symmetrical tridiagonal matrices $T_1$ and $T_2$ of about half the size. The tridiagonal element $\beta$ that isn't in either, you take out of $T$ in a $2\times 2$ square around the meeting point of $T_1$ and $T_2$ as a rank-one term $B$. Recursively decompose the resulting altered blocks $\hat T_1 = Q_1D_1Q_1^T$ and $\hat T_2 = Q_2D_2Q_2^T$, and when you're done, add $B$ and correct your diagonalisation. As far as I'm aware, this should look like:
$$\begin{align}
T &= \begin{bmatrix}Q_1 & 0\\0 & Q_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}D_1 & 0\\0 & D_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}Q_1^T & 0\\0 & Q_2^T\end{bmatrix} + B \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}Q_1 & 0\\0 & Q_2\end{bmatrix}\left(\begin{bmatrix}D_1 & 0\\0 & D_2\end{bmatrix} + \beta \vec z\vec  z^T\right)\begin{bmatrix}Q_1^T & 0\\0 & Q_2^T\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}Q_1 & 0\\0 & Q_2\end{bmatrix}Q_*D_*Q_*^T\begin{bmatrix}Q_1^T & 0\\0 & Q_2^T\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$
with $\vec z$ the relevant expression. Here's the problem: both Trefethen & Bau and Wikipedia only discuss how to get $D_*$; you do this via Newton's method applied to
$$f(\lambda) = 1 + \sum^m_{i=1} \frac{w_i^2}{d_i - \lambda}$$
where $\vec w = \sqrt{|\beta|}\vec z$ and $D = \begin{bmatrix}D_1 & 0\\0 & D_2\end{bmatrix}$, making the middle factor we want to diagonalise $D + \mathrm{sign}(\beta)\vec w \vec w^T$.

In fact, both of the above sources mention explicitly that the eigenvectors of $D$ and $D + \mathrm{sign}(\beta)\vec w \vec w^T$ cannot be the same in proving this expression. So ... where *did* the eigenvectors go? Since the eigenvectors of $D$ and $D + \mathrm{sign}(\beta)\vec w \vec w^T$ are not the same, that definitely means $Q_*$ can't just be trivially $I$. It might be true that we can find all eigenvalues recursively this way, but that's not what we set out to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvector computation for the divide-and-conquer eigensolver are actually a somewhat subtle matter. Section 5.3.3 of *Applied Numerical Linear Algebra* by Demmel has a great treatment. I'll focus on the case where $\beta > 0$, with the other case being similar.

The eigenvector of $D+\vec{w}\vec{w}^\top$ associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is $(D-\lambda I)^{-1}\vec{w}$. Using this formula, one can compute all the eigenvectors of $D+\vec{w}\vec{w}^\top$ in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ operations—easy peasy!

Unfortunately, when implemented directly, this formula has terrible accuracy issues. Instead, one should compute a new vector $\vec{z}$ such that the computed eigenvalues, with their numerical errors, are **exactly** the eigenvalues of $D+\vec{z}\vec{z}^\top$. $\vec{z}$'s entries are given by Löwner's formula

$$
|\vec{z}_i| = \left[ \frac{\prod_{j=1}^n (\lambda_j - D_{ii})}{\prod_{\substack{j=1\\j\ne i}}^n (D_{jj} - D_{ii})} \right]^{1/2}.
$$

We then apply the formula $(D-\lambda I)^{-1}\vec{z}$ to get accurate eigenvectors for $D+\vec{w}\vec{w}^\top$. After ensuring all columns have unit norm, this gives us $Q_*$ which we multiply into $\begin{bmatrix} Q_1 & 0 \\ 0 & Q_2 \end{bmatrix}$ to get the eigenmatrix for $T$.

The total cost for computation of all the eigenvectors is $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$, with the cost dominated by the final matrix-matrix multiplication to compute the eigenmatrix. The brave of heart can improve this to $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ with the [fast multipole method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_multipole_method), but this requires much pain and suffering. (It took 20 years after the proposal to accelerate the divide-and-conquer eigensolver with the fast multipole method for a brave soul to actually complete the task, as far as I know.)

Comment: I'll parrot Demmel's explanation. If you have two close eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\lambda'$, then $(D-\lambda I)\vec{w}$ and $(D - \lambda'I)\vec{w}$ are supposed to be orthogonal vectors, but the formula's are "two close". More specifically, the error comes from when both $\lambda$ and $\lambda'$ are very close to a diagonal entry of $D$. This causes errors both in the Newton iteration and the evaluation of $(D-\lambda I)^{-1}\vec{w}$.

Comment: Great answer. If I'm correct, the gist seems to be that errors in $\lambda$ courtesy of Newton's method are amplified by $\vec v = (D - \lambda I)^{-1}\vec w$. (By the way, where does that come from? Also, I presume this amplifying process is solving a system i.o. explicit inversion, right?) Is Löwner stabler in this sense, and do you have a reference for the formula for $\vec z$ (with perhaps slightly clearer product bounds)? Lastly, I think the last paragraph is touched on in T&B, without mentioning *how* to get there; nice! Would computing the eigenvectors iteratively via Rayleigh work?

Comment: (Perhaps good to say: I posted half of the above comment accidentally, so eepperly16's first comment is probably a response to the first half of my comment below it.)

Comment: A good reference is [Gu and Eisenstat](https://cpsc.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/tr932.pdf); see Lemma 2 for Löwner's formula and Eq. (3.10) for a rigorous treatment of its numerical stability. Note that the divide-and-conquer scheme is slightly different than in Demmel/TB, but the jist is the same. To elaborate on my previous comment, the issue with the naïve formula is that Newton iteration and $(D-\lambda I)^{-1}\vec{w}$ both, in general, involve subtraction of very close numbers leading to catastrophic cancellation. At a high level, Löwner compensates this by taking ratios of...

Comment: ...these differences, which has more desirable stability properties. I can't comment on the accuracy and stability of computing the eigenvectors by Rayleigh; my guess is that this will lead to good eigenvectors. Having to do Rayleigh kind of defeats the point of doing divide-and-conquer though, namely that DC is faster. @Mew

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. My suggestion for using Rayleigh was rooted in T&B not giving any other method for computing eigenvectors from eigenvalues, but it seems like divide-and-conquer works too after all.